# What are the dangers of "style-src: 'unsafe-inline'"?

Tags: web-application, content-security-policy, css

This is a common sight in content security policies:

```
style-src 'unsafe-inline'
```

I know that this "UI redressing attacks" that can be use for phishing or just defamation. But are there other threats as well? In particular, I am interested in:

- Script execution
- Data exfiltration

Can a liberal CSP for styles lead to any of those? If so, how?

Comment: (Strongly) related: [Cross site styling vulnerability?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/154629/cross-site-styling-vulnerability). You might want to point to that question in your question, and limit this question specifically to CSP issues (eg bypass of other CSP directives via this one), but exclude CSS injection in general.

Comment: One of the comments in Dropbox sees this as a form of separating code on the website via referencing to whitelisted source instead.  "This enforces code-data separation: all code running in the page has to come from script files in a whitelist of sources".